# action of $GL_3$ on $P^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-groups

> Find the action of $GL_3(K)$ on $\mathbb P_k^2 $, and compute its
>   orbits and also the isotropy groups for all its orbits.

($K$ is an algebraically closed field)

I know that $GL_3$ acts on $P_k^2 $ via the standard action on $K^3$ but how can I compute the orbits and the isotropy groups?

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Orbit(s) should be clear! Do you have a hunch?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: I suppose no, $G.x= \{ g \cdot x| g \in GL_3\} $ will be the $ 1 \times 3 $ matrix obtained by the multiplication $ (x \quad y \quad z) A$ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\operatorname{GL}_3(K)$ acts transitively on $K^3\setminus\{0\}$ because for any nonzero $v\in K^3$, you can find an invertible linear map $\phi:K^3\to K^3$ that maps $(1,0,0)$ to $v$, say. Hence, the orbits in $K^3$ are $\{0\}$ and $K^3\setminus\{0\}$. In $\mathbb P^2_K$, there is no origin point, so the space itself is one big orbit.

To compute the stabilizer, you only have to compute the stabilizer of a single point. Indeed, let us compute the stabilizer $H$ of $[1:0:0]$. Then, $H$ consists of all invertible matrices that map the line $K\cdot(1,0,0)$ to itself. That would be the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 x & a & b \\
 0 & h_{11} & h_{12} \\
 0 & h_{21} & h_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $h\in\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$, $x\in K^\times$ and $a,b\in K$. This is a parabolic subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Just one question: Why $GL_3(K)$ acts transitively in $K^3 \{0\}$ ? Thank you.

Comment: It was too obviuous sorry...Thank you one more time for your answer and your explanation.